# If “Word” In Column A, Add that “Word” to An Empty Column “B”

Tags: python, dataframe, preprocessor

I have a DF

**Weather_opinion:**

```
"the weather is cold"      
"it's quite sunny today"      
"it's raining"         
"today the climate seems to be pleasant"      
"I feel dizzy today"
```

**And a list:**

```
list_tags = ["cold", "sunny" "raining" "pleasant", "hot", "dry"]
```

So, if a tag is present in a row of the DF, I want to add another column, with the tag. If no word from the list is present in the DF add some generalized tag.

So, the new output would be

**Weather_opinion ~ tag:**

```
"the weather is cold" ~ "cold"      
"it's quite sunny today" ~ "sunny"      
"it's raining" ~ "raining"       
"today the climate seems to be pleasant" "pleasant"     
"I feel dizzy today" ~ "others"
```

Comment: What if more than one word is present?

Comment: And `df` is a list, tuple, dict, file ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
DF = [
    "the weather is cold",
    "it's quite sunny today",      
    "it's raining",
    "today the climate seems to be pleasant",      
    "I feel dizzy today"
]

list_tags = ["cold", "sunny" "raining" "pleasant", "hot", "dry"]

for option in DF:
    found_tag = "others"
    for tag in list_tags:
        if tag in option:
            found_tag = tag
            break
    print(option, found_tag)
```